# Set "training=False" of "tf.layers.batch_normalization" when training will get a better validation result

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I use TensorFlow to train DNN. I learned that Batch Normalization is very helpful for DNN , so I  used it in DNN.

I use "tf.layers.batch_normalization" and follow the instructions of the API document to build the network: when **training**, set its parameter "**training=True**", and when **validate**, set "**training=False**". And add **tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)**.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_node_num=257*7
output_node_num=257

tf_X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,input_node_num])
tf_Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,output_node_num])
dropout_rate=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
flag_training=tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
hid_node_num=2048

h1=tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(tf_X, hid_node_num, activation_fn=None)
h1_2=tf.nn.relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(h1,training=flag_training))
h1_3=tf.nn.dropout(h1_2,dropout_rate)

h2=tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h1_3, hid_node_num, activation_fn=None)
h2_2=tf.nn.relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(h2,training=flag_training))
h2_3=tf.nn.dropout(h2_2,dropout_rate)

h3=tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h2_3, hid_node_num, activation_fn=None)
h3_2=tf.nn.relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(h3,training=flag_training))
h3_3=tf.nn.dropout(h3_2,dropout_rate)

tf_Y_pre=tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h3_3, output_node_num, activation_fn=None)

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf_Y-tf_Y_pre))

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i1 in range(3000*num_batch):
        train_feature=... # Some processing
        train_label=...  # Some processing
        sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={tf_X:train_feature,tf_Y:train_label,flag_training:True,dropout_rate:1}) # when train , set "training=True" , when validate ,set "training=False" , get a bad result . However when train , set "training=False" ,when validate ,set "training=False" , get a better result .

        if((i1+1)%277200==0):# print validate loss every 0.1 epoch
            validate_feature=... # Some processing
            validate_label=... # Some processing

            validate_loss = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={tf_X:validate_feature,tf_Y:validate_label,flag_training:False,dropout_rate:1})
            print(validate_loss)
```

Is there any error in my code ?
if my code is right , I think I get a strange result:

when **training**, I set "**training = True**", when **validate**, set "**training = False**", the result is not good . I print validate loss every 0.1 epoch , the validate loss in 1st to 3st epoch is

```
 0.929624
 0.992692
 0.814033
 0.858562
 1.042705
 0.665418
 0.753507
 0.700503
 0.508338
 0.761886
 0.787044
 0.817034
 0.726586
 0.901634
 0.633383
 0.783920
 0.528140
 0.847496
 0.804937
 0.828761
 0.802314
 0.855557
 0.702335
 0.764318
 0.776465
 0.719034
 0.678497
 0.596230
 0.739280
 0.970555
```

However , when I change the code "**sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={tf_X:train_feature,tf_Y:train_label,flag_training:True,dropout_rate:1})**" , that : set "**training=False**" when **training**, set "**training=False**" when **validate** . The result is good . The validate loss in 1st epoch is

```
 0.474313
 0.391002
 0.369357
 0.366732
 0.383477
 0.346027
 0.336518
 0.368153
 0.330749
 0.322070
 0.335551
```

Why does this result appear ? Is it necessary to set "training=True" when training, set "training=False" when validate ?

Comment: How big is your batch_size?

Comment: @Ishamael The data I use for training is generated in real time. The **batch_size** of each generated data is **not fixed**, and each batch usually has 300 to 500 samples. 
(I have another question: in the general DNN training , it's common to **set batch_size to a fixed value**, for example, set batch_size = 1000, then each batch has 1000 samples. I would like to know whether DNN training must **ensure that the batch_size fixed**? For example, the 1st batch has 300 samples, the 2nd batch has 500 samples, and the 3rd batch has 400 samples... Is this way consistent with DNN theory?)

Comment: Variable batch size should be fine. Given that your data is generated, are samples within a generated batch more similar to each other than samples across generated batches? If yes, it would be a problem for batch norm

Comment: @Ishamael Yes, samples **within a generated batch** are more similar to each other than samples **across generated batches** .
I probably understand why the results are not good when setting "**training=true**" in training , and results are good when setting "**training=false**" in training :

Comment: @Ishamael I think the reason is :
Because **tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)** is used, both the global mean **mean_global** and the global variance **var_global** are updated by the batch mean **mean_batch** and the batch variance **var_batch** when train the DNN , regardless of "**training=true**" or "**training=false**".

Comment: @Ishamael When setting "**training=true**" , each batch of samples are normalized with **mean_batch** and **var_batch**. When setting "**training=false**" , each batch of samples are normalized with the global mean **mean_global** and the global variance **var_global**. Between different batches, the difference of **mean_batch** and the difference of **var_batch** is **large**, but the difference of **mean_global** and the difference of **var_global** is **small**.
Do you think this explanation is reasonable ?

Answer (score 17):

**TL;DR**: Use smaller than the default momentum for the normalization layers like this:

```
tf.layers.batch_normalization( h1, momentum = 0.9, training=flag_training )
```

**TS;WM**:

When you set `training = False` that means the batch normalization layer will use its internally stored average of mean and variance to normalize the batch, not the batch's own mean and variance. When `training = False`, those internal variables also don't get updated. Since they are initialized to `mean = 0` and `variance = 1` it means that batch normalization is effectively turned off - the layer subtracts zero and divides the result by 1.

So if you train with `training = False` and evaluate like that, that just means you're training your network without any batch normalization whatsoever. It will still yield reasonable results, because hey, there was life before batch normalization, albeit admittedly not that glamorous...

If you turn on batch normalization with `training = True` that will start to normalize the batches within themselves and collect a moving average of the mean and variance of each batch. Now here's the tricky part. The moving average is an ***exponential moving average***, with a default momentum of ***0.99*** for [`tf.layers.batch_normalization()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization). The mean starts at 0, the variance at 1 again. But since each update is applied with a weight of ***( 1 - momentum )***, it will asymptotically reach the actual mean and variance in infinity. For example in ***100*** steps it will reach about ***73.4%*** of the real value, because ***0.99<sup>100</sup>*** is ***0.366***. If you have numerically large values, the difference can be enormous.

So if you have a relatively small number of batches you processed, then the internally stored mean and variance can still be significantly off by the time you're running the test. Then your network is trained on properly normalized data and is tested on mis-normalized data.

In order to speed up the convergence of the internal batch normalization values, you can apply a smaller momentum, like ***0.9***:

```
tf.layers.batch_normalization( h1, momentum = 0.9, training=flag_training )
```

(repeat for all batch normalization layers.) Please note that there is a downside to this, however. Random fluctuations in your data will "tug" on your stored mean and variance a lot more with a small momentum like this and the resulting values (later used in inference) can be greatly influenced by where you exactly stop the training, which is clearly not optimal. It is useful to have as large a momentum as possible. Depending on the number of training steps, we generally use ***0.9***, ***0.99***, ***0.999*** for ***100***, ***1,000***, ***10,000*** training steps respectively. No point in going over ***0.999***.

Another important thing is proper randomization of the training data. If you're training first with let's say the smaller numeric values of your whole data set, then the normalization will converge even slower. Best to completely randomize the order of training data and making sure you use a batch size of at least 14 (rule of thumb.)

---

Side note: it is known that zero debiasing the values can speed up convergence significantly, and the [ExponentialMovingAverage class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage#__init__) has this feature. But the batch normalization layers don't have this feature, save for [`tf.slim`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim)'s [batch_norm](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L429), if you're willing to restructure your code for slim.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that you set Training = False improves performance is that Batch normalization has four variables (beta, gamma, mean, variance). It is true that mean and variance don't get updated when Training = False. However, gamma and beta still get updated. So your model has two extra variables and thus has a better performance.

Also, I guess that your model has a relatively good performance without batch normalization.