# Batch normalization setup train and test time

Tags: keras, batch-normalization

Recently ,I read so many articles talking about keras batch normalization had been discussed a lot.

According to this website:
[Set “training=False” of “tf.layers.batch_normalization” when training will get a better validation result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047653/set-training-false-of-tf-layers-batch-normalization-when-training-will-get-a)

The answer said that:

> If you turn on batch normalization with training = True that will start to normalize the batches within themselves and collect a moving average of the mean and variance of each batch. Now here's the tricky part. The moving average is an exponential moving average, with a default momentum of 0.99 for tf.layers.batch_normalization(). The mean starts at 0, the variance at 1 again. But since each update is applied with a weight of ( 1 - momentum ), it will asymptotically reach the actual mean and variance in infinity. For example in 100 steps it will reach about 73.4% of the real value, because 0.99100 is 0.366. If you have numerically large values, the difference can be enormous.

Since my batch size is small which means that more steps to take , and the difference could be big between training and test which lead bad result while predicting.

So,I have to set the `training=False` in `call` ,which again from the link above said that:

> When you set training = False that means the batch normalization layer will use its internally stored average of mean and variance to normalize the batch, not the batch's own mean and variance.

And I know that during test time we should use the moving mean and  moving variance from training time.And I Know the 
moving_mean_initializer can be set.

```
keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True, beta_initializer='zeros', gamma_initializer='ones', moving_mean_initializer='zeros', moving_variance_initializer='ones', beta_regularizer=None, gamma_regularizer=None, beta_constraint=None, gamma_constraint=None)
```

I am not sure if my opinion is correct or not:

(1) set the training =False when testing and`training=True` when training

(2)Use `hsitory_weight = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.{epoch:02d}.hdf5",save_weights_only=True,save_best_only=False)` to store the normalization weight(including moving average and variance of course gomma and beta)

(3) initialize it with what we get from step (2)

Not sure if anything that I mentioned above is wrong,if it it ,please do correct me.

And I am not sure how people typically do to deal with the problem?Is the one that I propose working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do some test ,After training ,

I set all batch layers's moving mean and moving variance to zero.

And it gives the bad result.

I believe at inference mode,the keras would use moving mean and moving variance.

And the part training flag,no matter you set the to `True` or `False` the only difference between these two is

whether the moving variance and moving mean would be updated or not.